# how to remove an item from django session?

Tags: python, django

I do have two items in `request.session.get('product_key').` I am trying to delete one product.

```
m =  request.session['product_key']
m.remove('768')
```

when i am trying to delete one product from the session its getting deleted from the variable but not from actual session. when i am printing m its giving me single product while i am typing `request.session.get('product_key')` its giving me two products.

So, how can i achieve so?

Edit:

I dont want to delete complete session, i want to delete one variable from the session,i have 2 items in one key name.
`print(request.session['product_key']) = ['123','768']`

Comment: you can remove session like "del request.session['applied_filter_Title']"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify a list in a session value - rather than changing or replacing the value completely - Django will not automatically know it needs to save the session. You need to tell it explicitly:

```
request.session.modified = True
```

See the docs on [When sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved).

Comment: but sir how to delete single value from the list of values in request.session['key'] ?

Comment: so my method is right,i have to just write this in my function `request.session.modified = True` ?

Comment: when i am declaring `request.session.delete()` do i need to write `request.session.modified = True` also?

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
del request.session['your key']
```

or

```
m = request.session.pop('your key')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

```
request.session["your key"].pop(index of the element you want to remove)
request.session.modified = True
```